# To get the file name in string

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, string, filenames

I have stored JSON file in my project folder externally by the following code,

```
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("JSON.json"), jSearializer.Serialize(modified_listofstrings));
```

but now in another method I want to read only name of that file, how I am suppose to do that,

if I read the file in string, I get the content of the file but I just want the name of the file by which it is stored.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

--- Edited question--- includes the code for filename.

```
string filename = ID.Replace(".", "_");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filename+".json"), jSearializer.Serialize(modified_listofstrings));
```

Comment: But is the name of the file not hard coded?

Comment: no..its not, Actually I am passing the ID as the file name which I take as input parameter from user, I will update the question for filename which I have stored.

Comment: Don't you have the file name already? Isn't it `json.json`? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It sounds like that you are able to read in the file content (which would of course mean that you know already the file name and path to open the file in the first place.)

Comment: @SaeedNeamati.. no, sorry, I wanted to make my question easy to understand so I gave static name but I came to know I was wrong, bottomline is name is going to keep on changing according to operation and I want to access the new name of the file every-time file is created and filename I will pass as ID.json where ID is the input parameter passed by user..hope you understand

Comment: @elgonzo .. I know the filename and its content , but I want to get the filename in my code programmatically.

Comment: @Reshma, when you want to read the file, do you have the ID available? If not, what other information is present at the time (information such as was present when the file was created)? You might also look at Saeed's answer, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can save `ID` in user's session, and in another method access it:

```
Session["FileName"] = filename;
```

and in your other method:

```
string fileName = Session["FileName"];
```

You can access session via:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the classes in `System.IO` namespace.

There are various ways of doing it. Below i have taken the virtual directory using `MapPath` and i search for files ending with '.json'. This should get you the file names

```
string path =  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/");
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.json");
```